# Mod Security - Request body with xml

Tags: xml, apache, parsing, soap, mod-security2

In mod security for detect and start an action for request body use `SecRule REQUEST_BODY`: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#REQUEST_BODY but when try parse the buffer of Soap action in XML body canot process it.

> Holds the raw request body. This variable is available only if the URLENCODED request body processor was used, which will occur by default when the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type is detected, or if the use of the URLENCODED request body parser was forced.

I try this:

```
SecRuleEngine on
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"
SecRule REQUEST_BODY "<password>\w{0,5}<\/password>" "id:77777771,log,deny,msg:'Week password'"
```

And in the post buffer:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
...
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 200

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:authenticate xmlns:tns="http://.../">
      <password>abc</password>
      ...
```

How to detect the response body of SOAP data and deny the match expreg value?

Answer (score 1):

I found a soluition in https://serverfault.com/questions/727596/mod-security-how-to-process-text-xml-request-body

```
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" "phase:1,nolog,pass,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=URLENCODED,id:12345"
SecRule REQUEST_BODY "<password.*?>.{0,6}?</password>" "phase:2,t:none,deny,msg:'Very short password',status:403,auditlog,id:67890"
```